# Lookup Column Making Creating a New List Item Take Way too Long

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, lookup-column

We have a Sharepoint list that contains information based on a daily receiving log for our receiving department. When it was set up, there was no archive workflows created, so now this list has grown to over 40000 items.

The issue is that one of the columns is a lookup where we can tie a new item to an existing item that we have already received. Because of the huge number of items, when you click "New Item" it takes forever for it to load all of the Parent Materials. Is there a way that I can trim this up so that it loads faster? I'm already working on creating an archive list for items new items that are added, but that doesn't help for the existing items.

I've looked all over to see if I can clean up the list by manually moving items over two years of age to the archive list, but I can't find anything. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Ben

Answer (score 0):

I d suggest you to archive your list:

**1**. Create a list template of you list with no content
**2**. Recreate it on the same level as the main lis
**3**.Create an SPD workflowthat'll copy an item to the new list and delete the original.  Make sure it doesn't have a triggering action
**4**.Use an Expiration Information Rights Policy to triger the workflow.

[read more here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/forums/sharepoint/en-US/e973fdaa-6856-4f40-919f-2048f7c5dd5a/how-to-archive-a-list-in-sharepoint-2010)